# Grails + mysql : The driver has not received any packets from the server

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, grails

I am attempting to connect my grails application to a Mysql database running locally via MAMP. I am getting the following error, and nothing else. I've tried every configuration. I don't think this is a Grails issue but more of a configuration issue. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Here is my **application.yml**

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:           
            dbCreate: update
            driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/development"
            username: "root"
            password: ""
```

I've tried with the port, without port different dialects and still no luck. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have you started  local `tomcat` server?

Comment: have you tried to access any remote dbs? just to localize if rdbms settings may be the cause

Comment: No I haven't, I will. Thank you.